# copy or move replace file and update version sharepoint CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, move, sputility

hi im using method for copy or move file on sharepoint. but i want to ask how to implement when it's duplicated it automatically replace and update version?

i've been try with this function but it's always

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: 'The destination file
> already exists

```
public void CopyFile(string SrcUrl, string DestUrl)
    {
        MoveCopyOptions option = new MoveCopyOptions();
        option.KeepBoth = false;
        MoveCopyUtil.CopyFile(this.clientContext,SrcUrl,DestUrl,true,option);
        this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

And my src

```
http://win-e636ggi1v13:55555/sites/srsrms/SRS%20Documents/Finance/fredytest/License%20Management.csv
```

and my Destination file

```
http://win-e636ggi1v13:55555/sites/srsrms/SRS%20Documents/Finance/paidi/Finance%20Folder/License%20Management.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a object of `MoveCopyOptions` that has boolean property `KeepBoth`. To handle similar file names you can set MoveCopyOptions. If you want to preserve both file after copying/moving set `MoveCopyOptions.KeepBoth` to true, else make it false.

Comment: hi i've been change this but doesn't work did im wrong ,i've been set to true for overwrite

 MoveCopyOptions option = new MoveCopyOptions();
            option.KeepBoth = true;
            MoveCopyUtil.CopyFile(this.clientContext,SrcUrl,DestUrl,true,option);
            this.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: hi @Akshay Randive i've been update why still error.

Comment: I am not  sure why this is not working. Can you try setting Overwite false and KeepBoth false

Comment: yes sir i've been try setting overwrite false and keepboot false.but doesn't work this function. im using sharepoint 2016 is that work with latest CSOM?